# irb does not print anything

Tags: ruby

I'm a newbie at ruby.
While I am using irb, something happens.(Nothings are printed)
Does anyone have any advise about this?
I cannot know even what search keyword would be OK for this situation.
(maybe an environment-specific problem? How do you think?)

```
irb(main):010:0> a = [3,2,1]
=> [3, 2, 1]
irb(main):011:0> a.each
=> #<Enumerable::Enumerator:0x7f413a20d668>
irb(main):012:0> a.each{|x| print x}
321=> [3, 2, 1]
irb(main):013:0> a.each do |x| print x end
321=> [3, 2, 1]
irb(main):014:0> 1.to 9
NoMethodError: undefined method `to' for 1:Fixnum
    from (irb):14
    from :0
irb(main):015:0> 1.to(9) do |x| print x done
irb(main):016:1> 1.to(9) { |x| print x }
irb(main):017:1> 1.to(9)
irb(main):018:1> 1.upto(9)
irb(main):019:1> 1.upto(9) do |x| print x done
irb(main):020:2> 1.upto(9) { |x| print x }
irb(main):021:2> print "x"
irb(main):022:2> abc
irb(main):023:2> a
irb(main):024:2> b
```

Comment: it's not `1.to 9`, it is `1.upto(9)`

Comment: @oldergod you are right. that's an error. but you can see corrected version just below some lines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What happened is that after the error, you typed `done` instead of `end`.

Nothing was executed until the block was parsed, but the `end` never came, so irb just kept reading stuff...

In the future just type ^C or ^D until you get back to the top level or the shell, and then start over.

Comment: Wow! thank you very much. I typed bash-grammar without intention. thank you again

Comment: plhn, if DigitalRoss was able to assist you, consider marking his answer as a solution so people know you've resolved your problem.

Comment: @SunnyJuneja OK :) , I can choose the answer after 10 mins from the point I asked. And I forgot to do that while I'm waiting!

Answer (score 3):

IRB is waiting for something to close (in this case the `do` block on line 15 needs an `end`).

You can notice this by watching the number after the line number (`:0`, `:1`, `:2`...): while it's positive, IRB wants you to close something.

You can press Ctrl+C to abort the current command and start a new one.

Comment: Thank you! (knowledge about :0, :1, :2 helped me much!)